# How do I copy data from an open workbook and paste and save into another CLOSED workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks MDM Log and MDM. Users need to enter the data in MDM Log and click an add button. The add button should then paste the entered data into the last row (dynamic-should change everytime a row is added) of the closed workbook, MDM and save it as well. The file MDM at no point in time should OPEN, it should only save the data which is added in MDM Log

Comment: You may be able to do this in vba, but the file you want to paste data into has to be open pasted into then saved at some point - if it is not visible to the user would that work?

Comment: In general you cannot write data into a file that is closed. You **always** need to open it then write your data and save/close it afterwards. This can be done in the background without showing the Excel Application. But still the file needs to be accessible exclusively (that means no other user/program has it open at the same time).

Comment: If MDM was a CSV file or similar, you could append data to it without it opening in Excel. But if it's an Excel file, your options will all involve the file opening in some form, perhaps invisibly/undetected.

Comment: @CLR But still you need to open the CSV for writing data, which means exclusive write access is needed (no other program/user can have it open for writing at the same time). This is also a file opening! • Since the OP doesn't tell the reason **why** he cannot open the file it is hard to give a adequate answer.

Comment: Agreed, the file needs to be locked.. but you can add a few lines to a CSV file with VBA in tenths of a second, completely invisibly to the user. You're right that the OP doesn't specifically say what they mean by 'no point in time should OPEN' - but most would probably assume that means in Excel because, let's face it, the alternative is pretty much impossible.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, I figured out that I have to open the file at some point in time and close it as well. My code works fine but it takes about a minute or two to add the entry into the MDM worksheet. How can I tackle this problem.

Comment: @RithwikSarma We cannot help you if you don't show your code and an example. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].